# Repo broken after clone

Tags: git, azure-devops, bitbucket, git-lfs

We have a bunch of repos in bitbucket. We plan to migrate to Azure Devops. When you clone a repo locally with regular git client, it works well, until you try to checkout another branch, than it complains:

```
Checking out files: 100% (3149/3149), done.
Downloading samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (32 KB)
Error downloading object: samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (a94f8a8): Smudge error: Error downloading samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (a94f8a8553caea8430dd4ca3cc01d4e318d19828f74cb65453ffb7f5d9e2f44d): [a94f8a8553caea8430dd4ca3cc01d4e318d19828f74cb65453ffb7f5d9e2f44d] LFS object not found: [404] LFS object not found
```

Errors logged to C:\uork\xxx.git\lfs\logs\20190202T091631.1131179.log

```
$ git-lfs.exe filter-process
Error downloading object: samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (a94f8a8): Smudge error: Error downloading samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (a94f8a8553caea8430dd4ca3cc01d4e318d19828f74cb65453ffb7f5d9e2f44d): batch request: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255

exit status 255
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.Wrap
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:74
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfsapi.(*Client).NewRequest
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfsapi/client.go:39
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*tqClient).Batch
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:60
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.Batch
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:44
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*TransferQueue).enqueueAndCollectRetriesFor
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:432
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*TransferQueue).collectBatches.func1
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:354
runtime.goexit
        C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197
batch request
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.Wrap
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:74
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*tqClient).Batch
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:62
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.Batch
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/api.go:44
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*TransferQueue).enqueueAndCollectRetriesFor
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:432
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq.(*TransferQueue).collectBatches.func1
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tq/transfer_queue.go:354
runtime.goexit
        C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197
Error downloading samples/ReactNativeSignalR/SignalRChat/wwwroot/favicon.ico (a94f8a8553caea8430dd4ca3cc01d4e318d19828f74cb65453ffb7f5d9e2f44d)
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.Wrapf
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/errors.go:85
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs.(*GitFilter).downloadFile
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:98
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs.(*GitFilter).Smudge
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:59
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.smudge
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:127
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.filterCommand
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_filter_process.go:118
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:477
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:551
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.Run
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/run.go:77
main.main
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:35
runtime.main
        C:/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:185
runtime.goexit
        C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197
Smudge error
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.NewSmudgeError
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:256
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs.(*GitFilter).Smudge
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/lfs/gitfilter_smudge.go:68
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.smudge
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_smudge.go:127
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.filterCommand
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/command_filter_process.go:118
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:477
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:551
github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands.Run
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commands/run.go:77
main.main
        C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/git-lfs.go:35
runtime.main
        C:/Go/src/runtime/proc.go:185
runtime.goexit
        C:/Go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197

Current time in UTC:
2019-02-11 12:26:57

ENV:
LocalWorkingDir=C:\uork\repodir
LocalGitDir=C:\uork\repodir\.git
LocalGitStorageDir=C:\uork\repodir\.git
LocalMediaDir=C:\uork\repodir\.git\lfs\objects
LocalReferenceDir=
TempDir=C:\uork\repodir\.git\lfs\tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=3
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=C:\uork\repodir\.git\lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic
UploadTransfers=basic
GIT_DIR=C:/uork/repodir/.git
GIT_EXEC_PATH=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core

Client IP addresses:
fe80::e7:bc8a:3fc4:ba23 10.120.23.118
fe80::80d6:68be:2b9c:37ef 10.0.0.4
fe80::8c36:6859:bb49:4ec1 172.22.152.113
fe80::c969:3d3e:900:3ab9 172.31.192.1
```

If I cat out one of the files inside the container that is generated after build I get:

```
cat xxx.png
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:9875270489d0c222f5d6b8a334f5f54fc9faf7aa0a9bd709a2d23a7b8412735b
size 4975
```

If I replace it with new file (upload file manually through UI). I get normal output:

```
cat xxx.png
�PNG

IHDR  J      �7{�   s��O�   PLTE�������ڹ�������ڷ�������
omited
```

It doesnt throw these errors if I use HTTP pull, but it does prompt me another time for my credentials, another error with ssh auth:

```
git lfs fetch --all
fetch: 121 object(s) found, done
fetch: Fetching all references...
batch request: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
batch request: git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).: exit status 255
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://bitbucket.org/xxx/yyy.git/info/lfs'
```

Also, not sure where this error comes from:

```
C:/Users/ttaylorr/go/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170
```

this path is not on my workstation.

EDIT: Everything seems to work fine when checking out with SourceTree. but after uploading to Azure DevOps these errors appear again. I've tried manual upload with `git remote add` and importing from the Azure DevOps UI. no difference

EDIT: on a fresh checkout i get this:

```
Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
        src/xxx/wwwroot/favicon.ico
```

seems related:
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/904
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3289

Comment: The log suggests `Permission Denied`.  Did your SSH keys change by any chance?

Comment: no, pulling works, after pulling it says something like: `pull succedd, checkout failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the answer was to do a git clone with https, after that do `git lfs fetch && git lfs checkout`. And pushing repo to ADO after that worked, however I also needed to enable `checkout files from lfs`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is related to Azure DevOps Services currently **doesn't support** **LFS over SSH**.

Please have a try to use **HTTPS** to connect to repos with Git LFS tracked files.

For more information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#im-using-git-lfs-with-azure-devops-services-and-i-get-errors-when-pulling-files-tracked-by-git-lfs).

> Azure DevOps Services currently doesn't support LFS over SSH. Use HTTPS to connect to repos with Git LFS tracked files.

Comment: good catch, thanks, but it doesnt really work with https as well, at least without some quirks